# stage.stage3Ds is empty when debuging on Kindle Fire HD 8.9"

Tags: air, kindle, stage3d

when i debug my program stage.stage3Ds is empty ( length 0 ) this gives me an error when i try to use it for programming. When I push a new Stage3D on to stage.stage3Ds and then use the requestContext3D() function, I never get the context3d_create event that allows me to move forward with program

Answer (score 2):

In the [Adobe AIR Application Descriptor XML file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WS99d2e2affb7f39bd-2d75e77d134e7ea3560-8000), set the following elements:

```
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>
<depthAndStencil>true</depthAndStencil>
```

#### Render Mode

> Specifies whether to use graphics processing unit (GPU) acceleration,
>   if supported on the current computing device.
>
> In order to leverage GPU acceleration of Flash content with AIR for
>   mobile platforms, Adobe recommends that you use renderMode="direct"
>   (that is, Stage3D) rather than renderMode="gpu". Adobe officially
>   supports and recommends the following Stage3D based frameworks:
>   Starling (2D) and Away3D (3D). For more details on Stage3D and
>   Starling/Away3D, see http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted/.

#### Depth and stencil

> Indicates that the application requires the use of the depth or
>   stencil buffer. You typically use these buffers when working with 3D
>   content. By default, the value of this element is false to disable the
>   depth and stencil buffers. This element is necessary because the
>   buffers must be allocated on application startup, before any content
>   loads.
>
> The setting of this element must match the value passed for the
>   enableDepthAndStencil argument to the Context3D.configureBackBuffer()
>   method. If the values do not match, AIR issues an error.
>
> This element is only applicable when renderMode = direct. If
>   renderMode does not equal direct, ADT throws error 118:

Comment: I get this Error when i try to debug on device with the changes added.  `code` Error occurred while packaging the application:

D:\Flash\Mobile Test\bin-debug\Main-app.xml(105): error 103: application.initialWindow.depthAndStencil is an unexpected element/attribute `code`

Comment: From [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570554/depthandstencil-throws-error-103-in-application-xml), it looks like depth and stencil was set to `false` instead of `true`.  Also, AIR SDK must be 3.2 or higher; whereas you are using AIR 3.1.

Comment: yeah any other ideas for my problem

Comment: Update your AIR SDK, or [overlay an updated AIR SDK](http://www.jasonsturges.com/2012/08/overlay-adobe-air-3-4-sdk-in-flash-builder-4-6/).

Comment: The only problem is I won't be able to debug on the device, because I have to include the new version of AIR with the program, which I believe means that I can't debug on the device.

Comment: The only problem is this "Adobe AIR version 3.1 is pre-installed on the Kindle Fire (2nd Generation) and Kindle Fire HD tablets. You can publish Adobe AIR 3 apps for the Kindle Fire tablets by packaging them as "captive runtime" apps. However, these captive runtime apps will not support on-device debugging."