# depthAndStencil throws Error 103 in application XML

Tags: air, stage3d

in trying to implement the answer to [stage.stage3Ds is empty when debuging on Kindle Fire HD 8.9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471574/stage-stage3ds-is-empty-when-debuging-on-kindle-fire-hd-8-9). I tried adding both renderMode and detailAndStencil to the application xml file but get this error when trying to debug to device.

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

D:\Flash\Mobile Test\bin-debug\Main-app.xml(10): error 103:            application.initialWindow.depthAndStencil is an unexpected element/attribute
```

The initialWindow portion of application xml file is below

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <depthAndStencil>true</depthAndStencil> 
</initialWindow>
```

Comment: What version of AIR are you targetting? (and depthAndStencil should be true, not false)

Comment: yeah it should be true. Im targeting AIR 3.1 for the Kindle Fire HD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like depthAndStencil option is only available with AIR 3.2 onwards.

Looking through the template file that is used to generate the app descriptor file:

```
[AIR SDK ROOT]\templates\air\descriptor-template.xml
```

The entry for depthAndStencil first appears in the template file that comes with the AIR 3.2 SDK.

Edit:

Confirmed. See release notes for 3.2 SDK: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/release-notes-developer-flash-player.html